# Trouble with getting all data from single csv file, but no issue with multiple csv files

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

This is kind of program that combine csv files under specified directory into one csv file.
if there are more than one file under /csv_tmp/ directory it works fine and give me the expected result.
if there is only one file under /csv_tmp/ directory it only write first row into the file under /csv_file/ directory.
But interesting thing is that when i insert `puts row` just under `CSV.foreach(f) do |row|` , it writes out all rows into new csv file.

```
 csv_files = Dir.glob("./csv_tmp/*")
 csv_files.each do |f|
   i=0
   CSV.foreach(f) do |row|
     #if i put one line code as below it gives me write out all rows(two lines)
     #puts row
     if i == 1
       CSV.open("./csv_file/test_output.csv","a+") do | com_data |
         com_data << row   
       end
     elsif i == 0
       if !File.exist?("./csv_file/test_output.csv")
         CSV.open("csv_file/test_output.csv","wb") do | com_data |
           com_data << row
         end
       end
     end
     i = i+1
   end
 end
```

Notice: All the csv files under csv_tmp/ directory consist with two lines.
I can`t figure out why it happens?
Ruby version is 1.9.3p448

I edited above script to the simple one as below:
result is same

```
csv_files = Dir.glob("./csv_tmp/*")
com_data = CSV.open("csv_file/test_output.csv","wb")
csv_files.each do |f|
  i=0
  CSV.foreach(f) do |row|
    com_data << row
    i = i+1
    puts i
  end
end
```

Get the results for `i` as below:
1 csv file : 
`1`
2 csv files: 
`1`
`1`
`2`
3 csv files: 
`1`
`2`
`1`
`2`
`1`
4 csv files: 
`1`
`2`
`1`
`2`
`1`
`2`
`1`
5 csv files: (as expected)
`1`
`2`
`1`
`2`
`1`
`2`
`1`
`2`

Comment: You only have two cases here, `i == 0` and `i == 1`. What if `i` becomes `2`?

Comment: @tadman there is no way to become 2, because i will be initiated every loop. and every csv file consist only two rows(two lines) , the loop insight only happens two times.

Comment: Not really, that gets incremented each line of your file. If you have more than two lines you're content to ignore those? What I think you need to do here is open the files once, then figure out which one to write to as you spin through that directory. Opening them up over and over is wasteful.

Comment: @tadman in normal case , there will be more than 10,000 files under csv_tmp/ directory each file only have two lines, i checked the value of the i and it only gives 0 and 1 as expected. this only happen while there is only one file. i only get 0 value which means the loop happen only once even there are two lines in targeted csv file.

Comment: Again, open your output files only once and I think this code will be a lot more clear.

Comment: @tadman thank you for your comment , it is same result even only open one time.

Comment: Try editing your question and replace that with the revised, cleaned-up code. I'm not sure exactly what you did to fix it.

Comment: @tadman I edited my question . added fixed script .

Comment: Looks like `i` is no longer doing anything useful so you can probably remove that as well. What's left seems entirely reasonable and should work, so it's confusing why it wouldn't. Have you tried putting in something like `puts row.inspect` inside the loop to see what's being read and written?

Comment: @tadman Yes , i tried row.inspect to see the actual output, it seems like there is something wrong with loop.i updated my question.

Comment: Some of your files in the test must be malformed or missing lines. Are you absolutely sure they're identical?

Comment: @tadman, I am sure ,actually those files were created with same program , i also tried to delete file which comes with wrong loop times. but same issue.